# How to get an update thread and render thread working smoothly together (on Linux)?

Tags: c, linux, opengl, pthreads, mutex

I'm trying to get a simple multi-threaded OpenGL application working. I have an update thread and a render thread. The way I've written them, they should be essentially taking turns running because they are mutex locked. Instead, the update thread will run tens of times, and then the render thread will runs tens of times. Here is the relevant code:

```
void glRender() {
    printf("glRender()\n");
    glXMakeCurrent(display, window, glXContext);
    glSetup();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(cosf(fDrawAngle), sinf(fDrawAngle));
        glVertex2f(cosf(fDrawAngle+2.1f), sinf(fDrawAngle+2.1f));
        glVertex2f(cosf(fDrawAngle+4.2f), sinf(fDrawAngle+4.2f));
    glEnd();
    glXSwapBuffers(display, window);
    glXMakeCurrent(display, 0, 0);
}

void * glThread(void * params) {
    while (bRunning) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        glRender();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

// Multi threaded version
void gameUpdateMT() {
    while (bRunning) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("gameUpdate()\n");
        windowUpdate();
        fDrawAngle += 0.01f;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

// Single threaded version - Runs fine.
void gameUpdateST() {
    while (bRunning) {
        printf("gameUpdate()\n");
        windowUpdate();
        fDrawAngle += 0.01f;
        glRender();
    }
}
```

gameUpdateMT() and glThread() are running in parallel. What would be causing one thread to loop so many times before the other one gets a chance to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread doesn't necessarily end its timeslice when it calls `pthread_mutex_unlock()`.   This being the case, it can easily loop around again and re-acquire the mutex (the waiters on a mutex aren't queued).

It's possible to use a condition variable to have the threads take turns - but that's just needlessly overcomplicating things.  If you want `glRender()` and `windowUpdate()` called alternately in sequence, then just have a single thread call them alternately, just as in your "singlethreaded" version.

There's no point having multiple threads if they never run concurrently.

Comment: I realize the program itself isn't practical; I'm trying to figure out the basics of multi-threading so that I can write something practical in the future. Obviously the two threads shouldn't run one after another in a practical application, but how can I keep from running into this problem in the future? A game can't update 500 times in a row and draw once every few seconds.

Comment: @JoeS: In this case, the precise form of the solution depends on the precise form of the problem (the general form of the solution is "condition variables").  If you want, for example, to have the render thread render a new frame as often as it can, then you could have the mutex protecting a frozen copy of the game state, with the game thread signalling a condition variable when a new copy of the game state is available.